# Como limitar linhas por mês no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-select, mariadb, select-limit

Tenho uma tabela de produtos comprados com data e preço, queria organizar numa query os dez mais comprados de cada mês, tipo:

```
mes     | nome   | total
janeiro | arroz  | 100
janeiro | feijão | 87
... até a décima
fevereiro |feijão | 110
... e assim vai dentro de um intervalo como seis meses
```

a tabela q tenho tem algo como

```
id | id_cliente | nome   | data_compra | preco_da_compra
32 | 12345678   | feijão | 2021-01-12  | 35 
33 | 121434366  | arroz  | 2021-01-11  | 25
34 | 223321213  | arroz  | 2021-01-11  | 22
```

tenho a query seguinte query

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(data_compra, "%b") as mes,
    nome,
    (select count(distinct nome) from compras where compras.nome = nome) as total
 WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(data_compra, "%b")= "Jan" 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

mas essa query pega só de janeiro os dez primeiros, eu queria pegar essa mesma query mês a mês sem precisar mudar manualmente a data, num intervalo como de janeiro a março.

Comment: faltam alguns detalhes como: qual o sgdb (mysql, postgres)?
e o que significa "mais comprados", é uma contagem da quantidade por nome, ou pela soma do preco_da_compra?

Comment: Nesse caso você teria que criar uma procedure, fazer um while mês a mês conforme o desejado e ir inserindo esses dados em uma tabela para consulta-la depois, ou simplesmente copiar esse select com o filtro do mês e repetir ele várias vezes com union all.

Comment: Você poderia ter informado a estrutura do banco e dado alguns dados que pudessem ajudar para o teste com a massa. Veja como criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver utilizando `ROW_NUMBER` em conjunto com `WITH`:

```
WITH totais AS (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.data_compra, "%b") AS mes,
         c.nome,
         COUNT(c.nome) AS total
    FROM compras c
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.data_compra, "%b"), c.nome
), delimitadores AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY t.mes ORDER BY t.total DESC) AS posicao
    FROM totais t
)
SELECT d.mes,
       d.nome,
       d.total
  FROM delimitadores d
 WHERE d.posicao <= 10
```

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/?fbclid=IwAR3hPUoIUvLmQSIIeSxmLlMfq3eHWJctX7RlGrmLKLVpJQXypUKwQUDtdpw#:%7E:text=ROW_NUMBER()%20is%20a%20window,values%20receiving%20different%20row%20numbers)
>
> `ROW_NUMBER()` is a window function that displays the number of a given row, starting at one and following the `ORDER BY` sequence of the window function, with identical values receiving different row numbers.

Em tradução livre:

> `ROW_NUMBER ()` é uma função de janela que exibe o número de uma determinada linha, começando em um e seguindo a sequência `ORDER BY` da função de janela, com valores idênticos recebendo diferentes números de linha.

---

> [`WITH`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/)
>
> The `WITH` keyword signifies a Common Table Expression (CTE). It allows you to refer to a subquery expression many times in a query, as if having a temporary table that only exists for the duration of a query.

Em tradução livre:

> A palavra-chave `WITH` referencia uma Common Table Expression (CTE). Ela permite que você se refira a uma expressão de subconsulta muitas vezes em uma consulta, como se tivesse uma tabela temporária que existe apenas durante a consulta.

---

Observação: Como você não forneceu a estrutura da tabela e uma massa mínima de dados para teste, a `query` pode conter erros de execução.